# Successively change cell value based on table content (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I am really new to vba and struggling with this issue :

I am trying to successively change one cells with data from a table, let the result being calculated and save the result into another table.

basically I would love it to work like that :

+++

- Manually input data into the base table (say "basetbl")
- The worksheet calculates the intermediary values with excel formulas
- The vba macro changes the value of a targeted cells, I believe the code would roughly look like below :

```
Dim n as Integer, i as Integer
n = range("basetbl[#Data]").Rows.Count
For i = 1 to n
   Range("E41") = basetbl(row i column1)
   ' refresh worksheet to calculate the final value'
   Application.Calculate
   'save the calculated result in cell C57 to the result table (say "resultstbl")'
   resultstbl[row i, column 2] = Range("C57")
   i + 1
   
   End For
```

The reason why I need the worksheet to be refreshed is because the cell E41 is linked to a look up for multiple values in the basetbl, and I need the whole worksheet to be recalculated. I also don't want to input the whole calculation into vba because I need to see the different steps in the calculation, change constants etc...
thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if referencing cells in a named table will work as expected (you may want to test with some dummy data and a few debug.print statements to be sure), but I'm sharing a slightly more refined version of your code below. If you need to read the VBA documentation on cell references for ranges, which might work better if you have trouble, [you can find that documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/excel/concepts/cells-and-ranges/reference-cells-and-ranges).

```
'declare variables
Dim wrksht As Worksheet 
Dim objLO_basetbl As ListObject 
Dim objLR_basetbl_rows As ListRows
Dim objLO_resultstbl As ListObject
Dim n as Integer 'number of rows
Dim i as Integer 'counter
Dim rngbasetbldata as Range 'basetbl data minus headers
Dim rngresultstbldata as Range 'basetbl data minus headers

'set initial variables
Set wrksht = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") 
Set objLO_basetbl = wrksht.ListObjects("basetbl")
Set objLR_basetbl_rows = objLO_basetbl.ListRows 
set rngbasetbldata = objLO_basetbl.DataBodyRange
set objLO_resultstbl = wrksht.ListObjects("resultstbl")
set rngresultstbldata = objLO_resultstbl.DataBodyRange

n = objLR_basetbl_rows.Count 'get row count for the basetbl; or, if your table has headers try this instead: 
'n = objLR_basetbl_rows.Count - 1 'or
'n = rngresultstbldata.rows.count

If NOT n = 0 Then 'check to make sure your table has some rows
    For i = 1 to n
        Range("E41").value = rngbasetbldata.cell(i, 1).value 'note: this form of cell reference probably won't work as you expect, you'll need to test and adjust
        Application.Calculate 'refresh worksheet to calculate the final value
        rngresultstbldata.cell(i, 2).value = Range("C57").value 'save calculated result from C57 to result table; same as above, this form of cell reference might need adjusting
        i = i + 1
    Next i
End If
```

Comment: Hello ! Many thanks I will check the VBA documentation on cell references for ranges